# INSERT INTO fails with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-insert, node-mysql

I am trying to insert some data with node.js. I have written the following code and installed MySQL support via npm, but I failed to `INSERT INTO` the table.

Here is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function BD() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        database: 'nodejs'
    });
    return connection;
}

app.post("/user/create", function(req, res) {
    var objBD = BD();

    var post = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    objBD.query('INSERT INTO users VALUES ?', post, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('success');    
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="/user/create" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
     <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username">
     <input type="text" id="password_input" name="password">
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Insert" class="btn">
</form>
```

The error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near .'username' = 'Test' , 'password' = 'test' at line 1

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Pay attention to the [documentation of `node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values):

> If you paid attention, you may have noticed that this escaping allows you to do neat things like this:
>
> ```
> var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
> var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
>   // Neat!
> });
> console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
> ```

Notice that they use `SET` instead of `VALUES`. `INSERT INTO ... SET x = y` is a valid MySQL query, while `INSERT INTO ... VALUES x = y` is not.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I spent one hour to fix this.

Comment: @TimWolla This is an awesome solution, but how can I call MySQL function inside an object?

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old post but thought I'd share that INSERT INTO...VALUES is a valid command (no SET) and very useful for bulk updates:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ?', [values])
```

where [values] is an array of arrays, each array containing those three fields and inserted as a record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

For others searching, I had this same issue, but it turns out it was a more complicated, unrelated issue. I wasn't declaring `'use strict';` at the very top of the document.

I know this in itself won't solve the database insert problem, but it pointed out parts of my entire script that were coded incorrectly, and once fixing those, it worked as expected.