# doubts as to the mysql and nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

in nodejs every time i try use

```
var geometry = 'GeomFromText(&rsquoPOLYGON('+Area1x+' '+Area1y+','+Area2x+' '+Area2y+','+Area3x+' '+Area3y+','+Area4x+' '+Area4y+','+Area1x+' '+Area1y+')&rsquo,0)';
 //   console.log(geometry);
var data = {
    "error":1,
    "Area":""
};
if(!!Areanome && !!Area1x){
var query =     connection.query("INSERT INTO likeyouarea VALUES(null,?,?)",[Areanome,geometry],function(err, rows, fields){
```

the commando in the sql expose this by         console.log(query.sql);

```
INSERT INTO area VALUES(null,'area2','GeomFromText(&rsquoPOLYGON(-30.02724579591031 -51.22842527925968,-30.027021410835776 -51.22754216194153,-30.027769165561978 -51.22727394104004,-30.02800603078958 -51.228153705596924,-30.02724579591031 -51.22842527925968)&rsquo,0)')
```

but the correct query is  and it's working but in console of phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO area VALUES(null,'area2',GeomFromText('POLYGON((-30.02724579591031 -51.22842527925968,-30.027021410835776 -51.22754216194153,-30.027769165561978 -51.22727394104004,-30.02800603078958 -51.228153705596924,-30.02724579591031 -51.22842527925968))',0))
```

How can I use the correct way usingo geoFromText it's a command not a string

I already look this [INSERT INTO fails with node-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779528/insert-into-fails-with-node-mysql)
but it's all according mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
var geometry = 'POLYGON('+Area1x+' '+Area1y+','+Area2x+' '+Area2y+','+Area3x+' '+Area3y+','+Area4x+' '+Area4y+','+Area1x+' '+Area1y+')';

...

var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO likeyouarea VALUES(null,?,GeomFromText(?,0))",[Areanome,geometry],function(err, rows, fields){ ... };
```

Comment: thanks this give me a light to understand the problem  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I missing a second ( in polygon

```
var geometry = 'POLYGON(('+Area1x+' '+Area1y+','+Area2x+' '+Area2y+','+Area3x+' '+Area3y+','+Area4x+' '+Area4y+','+Area1x+' '+Area1y+'))';
 //   console.log(geometry);
var data = {
    "error":1,
    "Area":""
};
if(!!Areanome && !!Area1x){
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO area VALUES(null,?,GeomFromText(?,0))",[Areanome,geometry],function(err, rows, fields){
```