# How to send array request with Postman and handle its transaction script with node.js to save in MySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, retrofit2, postman

In my Android application, I try to send a `List<MyClass> list` through Retrofit to my server database. Achieved some web services and scripts but with in array request I need a hand. I need to know how to send request from postman and handle it wth script (node.sj)

- **This is my database table (`kontrol`) at `phpAdmin` side**

[image]

`ogr_id` `tur_id` and `durum_id` are fields of my class object.

- **What I have tried is as script of it**

  var express = require('express');
  var utils = require('./custom_utils.js');

module.exports = function(database){
    var router = express.Router();

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var nesne = "merhaba";
    database.query('INSERT INTO kontrol (ogr_id, tur_id, durum_id,tarih) VALUES ? ', 
            [Array.from(req.body.ogrenciler).map(function(g){ return [g, nesne, 0]; })], function(err, results, fields){
                var n = results.length;
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ status: utils.respondMSG.DB_ERROR });
        }else if(n<1){
                    res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.DB_ERROR});
        }else {

            res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED});

        }
    });
});
return router;
```

};

- **Here is my Postman Request**

[image]

I am able to use Retrofit Call back serives due to postman result. What I am trying to do is sent a correct request and write a script to handle it at server side

{
    "ogrenciler" :
    [
        {
        "ogr_id" : 17,
        "tur_id" : 1,
        "durum_id": 2,
        "tarih":"2017-17-02"
        },
        {"ogr_id" : 74,
        "tur_id" : 1,
        "durum_id": 1,
        "tarih":"2017-17-02"
        }
    ]
}

As I told it  `ogr_id` `tur_id` `durum_id` are fields of my List Object, also would like to know if there is an more efficent request and of course its scirpt side. At Least I hope to hear some solutions to my first try

************************* **SOLVED - EDITED** *************************

**- What I am trying to send from Postman like**

[image]

**- Retrofit service method is**

```
{
@POST("saveOgrYoklama")
Call<YoklamaStatus> sendYoklamaList2(@Body Yoklama yoklama);
}
```

**- Model Classes to handle the values**

```
{
 public class Yoklama implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("tarih")
        private String tarih;

        @SerializedName("ogrenciler")
        private ArrayList<YoklamaOgrenciler> ogrenciler;

        public class YoklamaOgrenciler implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("ogr_id")
        private int ogr_id;

        @SerializedName("tur_id")
        private int tur_id;

        @SerializedName("durum_id")
        private int durum_id;
      }
    }
}
```

**- And Script of it**

```
var express = require('express');
var utils = require('./custom_utils.js');

module.exports = function(database){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

        var jsondata = req.body.ogrenciler;
        var values = [];
        //var mysqlTimestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var st = req.body.tarih;
        //console.log(st);
        var uzunluk = req.body.ogrenciler.length;
        for(var i=0; i< uzunluk; i++)
            values.push([ jsondata[i].ogr_id, jsondata[i].tur_id, jsondata[i].durum_id,st  ]);

        console.log(req.body.ogrenciler);
        console.log(values);
        console.log(jsondata);

        console.log("uzunluk is :"+uzunluk);
        console.log("Deneme asds");
        database.query('INSERT INTO kontrol (ogr_id, tur_id, durum_id, tarih) VALUES ? ', [values], function(err, results, fields){
                    var n = results.length;

                    console.log(results);
                    console.log("Affected Row Num : "+results.affectedRows);
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.json({ status: utils.respondMSG.DB_ERROR });
            }else if(n==NaN){
                        console.log("result NaN");
                        res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED});
            } else if(n==null){
                        console.log("result null");
                        res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED});
            }else if(n<1){
                        console.log("result < 1 ");
                        res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED});
            }else {
                res.json({status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED});
            }
            /**/
        });
    });
    return router;
};
```

**Be sure that you dont have *@FormUrlEncoded* above your service method. Babanız bu iyiliği yapmaz söyliim. Hope it will help others, lost many days on it**

Comment: This doesn't look right - `INSERT INTO kontrol (ogr_id, tur_id, durum_id, tarih) VALUES ?`

Comment: Yes I need to find right one just typed what I could, thought It would be better instead of sentences, most usefull link I have found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779528/insert-into-fails-with-node-mysql but ot solving what I need