# ER_PARSE_ERROR after inserting word with apostrophes

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

When I insert a word that has apostrophes in the HTML input I get this error

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near

For example: inserting word without apostrophes like "Hello world" works succesfully and I can see the row in the MySQL table. But, when I insert words like "that's" then I get the error.

I use varchar for the value row.

```
connection.query("IN­SERT INTO masstoadmin (`title`,`contact`,`­theuser`,`ptime`,`to­user`,`mass_stat`) VALUES ('"+title+"','"+cont­act+"','"+theuser+"'­,'"+ptime+"','"+tuse­r+"','"+nmasso+"')")­;
```

Comment: Learn about SQL injection and [how to escape values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: @robertklep i tried to use connection.escapeId and i still get the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO fails with node-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779528/insert-into-fails-with-node-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use placeholders, which also prevent SQL injections by properly escaping the values that you're passing into the query:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO masstoadmin (`title`,`contact`,`theuser`,`ptime`,`touser`,`mass_stat`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [ title, contact, theuser, ptime, tuser, nmasso ], ...)
```

Comment: i get this error connection.query("IN­­­SERT INTO masstoadmin (`title`,`contact`,`­­theuser`,`ptime`,`t­o­­user`,`mass_stat`­) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", [ title,contact,theuse­r,ptime,tuse­r,nmass­o]);
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @darknight see edit. For some reason, your code contained soft hyphens that were breaking the code. I removed them.

Comment: i get this error Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN­SERT INTO masstoadmin (`title`,`contact`,`theuser`,`ptime`,`to­user`,`mass_' at line 1

Comment: @darknight there were more junk characters in the code you posted, try again.